# Ubuntu 18.04 shows only the desktop pattern in external screen

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04, everything's fine but the video output to an external TV screen connected by HDMI.

I've looked for similar questions, *HDMI connection problems* , my case is quite different and weird.

PC monitor is ok. 
The external TV screen shows **only the desktop background pattern** with the circle'arcs draft of the beaver; **neither icons nor toolbar appear**.

Thus a sort of incomplete desktop shows up in the external TV screen while the one in the PC's main monitor is complete.

May someone give me a tip to solve the problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you move a window from your PC monitor to this external TV screen?

Comment: Yes I could. Thanks to your tip and other suggestion below I was able to solve by managing display config.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is the default behavior of Join Displays in Ubuntu 18.04 :

https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/372

Change the primary display (*Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Displays*) or install `gnome-extension-multi-monitor`.

Comment: You were right, I changed Display's settings in the config panel that you suggested and now screen output is fine. Thanks a lot.